# Is it possible to use cockroach gen_random_uuid() function inside JSON data while inserting into JSON datatype in cockroachDB

Tags: cockroachdb

I am new to cockroach DB and was wondering if the below ask is possible

One of the columns in my table is of JSON type and the sample data in it is as follows

```
 {
    "first_name": "Lola",
    "friends": 547,
    "last_name": "Dog",
    "location": "NYC",
    "online": true,
    "Education": [
        {
            "id": "4ebb11a5-8e9a-49dc-905d-fade67027990",
            "UG": "UT Austin",
            "Major": "Electrical",
            "Minor": "Electronics"
        },
        {
            "id": "6724adfa-610a-4efe-b53d-fd67bd3bd9ba",
            "PG": "North Eastern",
            "Major": "Computers",
            "Minor": "Electrical"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to replace the "id" field in JSON as below to get the id generated dynamically?

```
"id": gen_random_uuid(),
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this should be possible. To generate JSON data that includes a randomly-generated UUID, you can use a query like:

```sql
root@:26257/defaultdb> select jsonb_build_object('id', gen_random_uuid());
                jsonb_build_object
--------------------------------------------------
  {"id": "d50ad318-62ba-45c0-99a4-cb7aa32ad1c3"}
```

If you want to update in place JSON data that already exists, you can use the `jsonb_set` function (see [JSONB Functions](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v21.1/functions-and-operators#jsonb-functions)).

Comment: Thanks @paul for the reply. Let me try to implement the mentioned solution and see if my use case is satisfied